# how to retrieve an html 'path' element attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, webbrowser-control

I want to retrieve the "d" attribute value of an 'path' html element and show it in textbox(for test).

I tried the code below however it finds the element but nothing being added to the text box.

```js
foreach(HtmlElement elm in col) {
  if (elm.GetAttribute("className") == "highcharts-series") {
    HtmlElementCollection col2 = elm.Children;
    row = col2[0];
  }
}

textBox1.Text += row.GetAttribute("d");
```

Html element:

```
<g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible" zindex="0.1" transform="translate(30,325) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-5)">
           <path fill="rgba(69,114,167,0.05)" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" zindex="0"></path>
           <path fill="none" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" stroke="#4572A7" stroke-width="1" zindex="1" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
          </g>
```

Comment: Show the HTML. We cannot guess where or how it's coded

Comment: Can you please post your HTML element which has the class name "highcharts-series"